# RabbitMQ: Problem with " Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped" #8648

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, apple-m1

I have a problem with rabbitMQ on my local system.

I use docker with:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
```

Docker Desktop 4.20.1 (110738)
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc

Apple Macbook Pro with M1 Chip
Ventura 13.4.

I deleted all containers and images related to rabbitMQ.
Then when I do a:
`docker compose up -d`

I always get this error and rabbitMQ stopps:

```
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.984151+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.658039+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.659274+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.662647+00:00 [notice] <0.283.0> Feature flags: attempt to enable `stream_sac_coordinator_unblock_group`...
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.793670+00:00 [notice] <0.283.0> Feature flags: `stream_sac_coordinator_unblock_group` enabled
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1  | Segmentation fault
```

In the past it worked, like 5 months ago.

Reproduction steps
docker compose up -d

Expected behavior
that the container runs and does not exit

Additional context
docker compose logs

```
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:06.946635+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:06.966134+00:00 [notice] <0.230.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:06.973002+00:00 [notice] <0.230.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.539052+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.539748+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a/quorum/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.715984+00:00 [info] <0.261.0> ra system 'quorum_queues' running pre init for 0 registered servers
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.749375+00:00 [info] <0.262.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.786151+00:00 [notice] <0.267.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.857344+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> ra: starting system coordination
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.857635+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> starting Ra system: coordination in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a/coordination/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.868808+00:00 [info] <0.274.0> ra system 'coordination' running pre init for 0 registered servers
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.874965+00:00 [info] <0.275.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system coordination. 0 record(s) recovered
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.875747+00:00 [notice] <0.280.0> WAL: ra_coordination_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_coordination_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_coordination_log_closed_mem_tables
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.899618+00:00 [info] <0.230.0>
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.899618+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Starting RabbitMQ 3.12.0 on Erlang 25.3.2.2 [jit]
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.899618+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Copyright (c) 2007-2023 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.899618+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | ## ## RabbitMQ 3.12.0
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | ## ##
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | ########## Copyright (c) 2007-2023 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | ###### ##
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | ########## Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Erlang: 25.3.2.2 [jit]
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | TLS Library: OpenSSL - OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Release series support status: supported
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Support: https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Tutorials: https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Logs:
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 |
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Starting broker...2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0>
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> node : rabbit@4fb71bcd203a
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> home dir : /var/lib/rabbitmq
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> cookie hash : 44Zvpg2cVp6cjDhbQol+8w==
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> log(s) :
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:07.931672+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> data dir : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.762101+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.763087+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step rabbit_global_counters defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.765559+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step rabbit_osiris_metrics defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.766267+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.768305+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step rabbit_alarm defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.842402+00:00 [info] <0.299.0> Memory high watermark set to 3180 MiB (3335041843 bytes) of 7951 MiB (8337604608 bytes) total
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.909670+00:00 [info] <0.301.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring (disk free space: 103757205504, total memory: 8337604608)
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.910259+00:00 [info] <0.301.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.947319+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.948052+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step file_handle_cache defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.951092+00:00 [info] <0.304.0> Limiting to approx 1048479 file handles (943629 sockets)
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.952632+00:00 [info] <0.305.0> FHC read buffering: OFF
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.952887+00:00 [info] <0.305.0> FHC write buffering: ON
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.959581+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step worker_pool defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.960112+00:00 [info] <0.282.0> Will use 4 processes for default worker pool
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.960362+00:00 [info] <0.282.0> Starting worker pool 'worker_pool' with 4 processes in it
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.963564+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step database defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.969958+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Node database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4fb71bcd203a is empty. Assuming we need to join an existing cluster or initialise from scratch...
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.970398+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Configured peer discovery backend: rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.970722+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Will try to lock with peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.971745+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> All discovered existing cluster peers:
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.971909+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Discovered no peer nodes to cluster with. Some discovery backends can filter nodes out based on a readiness criteria. Enabling debug logging might help troubleshoot.
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:18.984151+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.658039+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.659274+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.662647+00:00 [notice] <0.283.0> Feature flags: attempt to enable stream_sac_coordinator_unblock_group...
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | 2023-06-22 08:12:20.793670+00:00 [notice] <0.283.0> Feature flags: stream_sac_coordinator_unblock_group enabled
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
rabbitmq-server-rabbitmq-1 | Segmentation fault
```

Thanks for your help